# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 in mongoose6.1.13

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, windows-10

I'm using NodeJS with MongoDB using MongoDB package. When I run mongod command it works fine and gives "waiting for connection on port 27017". So, mongod seems to be working. But MongoClient does not work and gives an error when I run node index.js code.
The error is given below in the picture.

I have installed mongo DB 5.0.5, mongoose package 6.1.13 and my code is-

```
// getting-started.js
 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
   await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
}
```

I'm able to connect the database by console log and windows power shell but not by the node.js

[Error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brGYj.png)

Comment: try `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test`